# storage:link not working on hosting cPanel

Tags: laravel, storage, hosting, cpanel, laravel-storage

I've created a storage link with `php artisan storage:link` and it's working totally fine on *localhost*, However, when I deploy my project on a shared hosting, it does not render any images. This is my hosting directory structure:

```
- home2/username
:   + other hosting folders
:   - MyLaravelWebSite
:   :   + other_laravel_folders
:   :   - storage
:   :   :   - app
:   :   :   :   - public
:   :   :   :   :   -images
:   :   :   :   :   :   * some-image.jpg
:   :   :   :   * gitignore
:   :   :   + framework
:   :   :   + logs
:   - public_html
:   :   + assets
:   :   + storage // symlink
:   :   * index.php
```

Images are uploading without any issue, but when I try to render them they do not render, while they're being rendered absolutely fine on localhost. I think the *symbolic link* is not working. How can I make it work?

*P.s: I don't have any access of CLI on cPanel.*

Comment: what is your `APP_URL` on `.env` file? is it the url of your project?

Comment: @hasan05 it's `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: So, where your image uploads actually? I think its in your public_html folder.
so, you have to change `APP_URL=${your current url}`

Comment: No, it's uploading in `storage>app>public>images` like it's suppose to upload. It's just that whenever i try to use `asset('storage/path/to/image.jpg');` the symbolic link is not working...

Comment: did you tried by change `APP_URL` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP and Laravel helper methods to do the same, just run this code once (e.g. add it in your controller and call it once) to create storage link manually:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

File::link(
    storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update **filesystems.php**

```php
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path() . '/uploads',// upload file in public dir
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads', // help to get Storage::url() 
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

put this in `filesystems.php` then your all file will be saved in  `public/uploads` folder
and to get url this function `Storage::disk('public')->url($dbImageUrl);`  will be work

this is for cpanel if you are not able to create symlink  then

Comment: That's a fine work around... But I need to save my images in laravel storage and get them from there. It's uploading them in storage, but the symbolic link is not working in cPanel. I want to know how can I create a new link with my defined path.

Comment: symbolic link is not working on some cpanel so i used this and here your upload folder will be work link storage folder only all file will be public if you want safe file then you can try via php

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a file in your public folder (`filename.php`). Add the code and save

```
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
```

browse the file you created `site.com/filename.php`

Credit: https://www.nicateliyev.com/en/post/how-create-symbolic-link-laravel-website-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the answers above with out making any changes to the file config system is to

1. Delete the storage link folder created on your local host from your c-panel
2. Create a route to run you php artisan storage:link command as below

   `Router::get('/storage_link', function (){ Artisan::call('storage:link'); });`
3. on your bowser got to the route /storage_link,.. this will create a new system link to you storage file