# Image source not readable - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I've used storage to store image files using laravel intervention library. I can not access the image in the storage.

Error

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable
```

Controller

```
$imagePath1 = request('image1')->store('productsImg', 'public');
$thumbPath1 = request('image1')->store('productsImg/thumbnail', 'public');
$image1 = Image::make(("storage/{$thumbPath1}"))->fit(600, 600);
```

In the local project using xamp, I can solve this err using php artisan storage:link.
However I don't have terminal access for the server. So I cannot run the command. How can I provide storage permission without using terminal?

Comment: if u can't run `php artisan storage:link.` then u should use `public` dir as storage path

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036552/storagelink-not-working-on-hosting-cpanel/60036779#60036779

Comment: you have to give permissions to access in storage, can use `exec('chmod -R 777 ' . $yourpathfolder);` to give temporary permission just before storing the image, it would revert back to original permission after execution of your function. NOTE: this is if your server os is linux/unix