# Laravel Storage Link Not Worrking on shared server

Tags: php, laravel, storage

```
<img src="{{Storage::url($data->image) }}" class="img-thumbnail " alt="{{ $data->title }}" style="width:100px" >


'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],

],
'links' => [
       
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
    ],
```

> http://mydomain/storage/service_img/EfLnGE7tuWwogAL3TaHI5yRAICVamnGNM4D0NE3a.jpg

**

> Doesn't work on shared server 
> Note:
> I haven't tried all the methods available in stackoverflow

**

Comment: you should try this for shared hosting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036552/storagelink-not-working-on-hosting-cpanel/60036779#60036779  it will upload file on public dir

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: it didn't store in public dir ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [storage:link not working on hosting cPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036552/storagelink-not-working-on-hosting-cpanel)

Comment: <img src="http://filmtadi.com/uploads/service_img/v2x2LxzwAGIbGJ17m56mbXgtMnMoRuSLtj5obqT1.jpg>   not working

Comment: then check in you `public/uploads` have the file or not

Comment: and use `Storage::disk('public')->put('filename',$request->file)` then it will store in correct place

Comment: public/uploads->no not there

Comment: then you need to upload in correct `stoarge::disk()`

Comment: `Storage::disk('public')->put('service_img',$request->image)` like this

Comment: myproject/public/uploads/service_img/v2x2LxzwAGIbGJ17m56mbXgtMnMoRuSLtj5obqT1.jpg  not working again

Comment: How do I connect with the public_html folder

Comment: `Storage::disk('public')->url($dbPath)` use this to show image

Comment: {{ Storage::disk('public')->url($data->image) }}"'   i try everything but it doesn't work

Comment: what url is generated ?

Comment: http://filmtadi.com/uploads/service_img/L4QeXsgcXi1CdNnzBiEs0eeaHcUivEEUWLUvRu91.jpg  =>  this URL

Comment: then may be file is not stored in public dir

Comment: I think so thank you for your effort